# Is there two version of ulaw and alaw encoding in audio compression?

Tags: audio, channelcoding, conversion

I am new to encoding in audios and i have searched for ulaw and alaw and found there is conversion from audio to this encoding CCITT alaw/ulaw and as i have known alaw/ulaw belongs to ITUT group not CCITT so Is there two standards for conversion audio to  [alaw/mulaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20slightly%20different,other%20countries%20outside%20North%20America.) ?

[image: here is the ITU-T]
and this conversion about [CITT ulaw](https://www.yopo.co.uk/creating-ulaw-ccitt-audio/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can choose the µ parameter freely in µ-law encoding. So, there's as many different µ-law encodings as there are possible µ; of course, only very few are standardized.

The same applies to the A in A-law.

You might want to read the wikipedia articles on µ-law and A-law, instead of just the G.711 article.

Comment: you are talking about choosing parameters to change expanding and compression of the signal but what i want to know is that there is two standards for ulaw and alaw or not ?

Comment: I explicitly answered that.

Comment: maybe the confusion for me as ITUT and CCITT have become as CCITT so this is the confusion of my understanding so i thought there is no more than one ulaw/alaw CCITT